# Remove trailing zeros when using siunitx

Tags: siunitx

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 4
]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\horse[1]{\calc{3.5*sin(pi/#1)}}

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\num{\horse{\i}}\quad}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Is it possible to remove the trailing zeros from the numbers? (In this case it means getting `3.5` instead of `3.5000` and `1.75` instead of `1.7500`.)

**Update**

It seems that it's not possible to achieve what I would like; should the question therefore be closed?

Comment: You've asked for 4 places of precision: that's what you've got

Comment: @JosephWright The problem is that I would like the numbers with no trailing zeros to have four decimals precision.

Comment: Those numbers _do_ have four decimal place precision. The trailing zeroes in 3.5000 signal that the true value is between 3.49995 and 3.50005. Think carefully about _why_ you want to remove them.

Comment: @EthanBolker The point is that the exact values are `7/2` and `7/4`.

Comment: How to convey that is an interesting puzzle. Can you write those two as rational fractions? Are the other values rational fractions with nonterminating decimals, or just four decimal places? If the latter, consider writing 3.5 and 3.0311... to tell your story.

Comment: @EthanBolker They can't be written as fractions if I want `siunitx` to print them automatically. (Also, the other values are not rational; I'm calculating different values involving sine.)

Comment: Remember: `siunitx` is a package for dealing with _physical measurements  and quantities_. You can't have `7/2 cm` or whatever: you can have `3.5000 cm` with an uncertainly in as @EthanBolker suggests. Also, if you really want to print a fraction within say `\SI` then `parse-numbers = false` is available.

Comment: @JosephWright I know it is for physical measurements; the only reason I asked is that your package has so many great features so I hoped that it was somehow possible. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I will see what I can come up with in the next release, of course!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg So, if the number is `142589/142587=1.0000140...`, would you represent it as `1`?

Comment: @egreg No, because then it is known that it is a fraction. This is for geoemtry at first-year student highschool level, so since we are dealing with trigonometric functions and I have told them that, say, sin(pi/6) = 1/2, I would like to be abel to get `3.5` instead of `3.5000`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg Don't use decimal numbers, but *only* fractions

Comment: @egreg I know what you meen but this is for the final result; then they are allowed to write it as decimal numbers.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg They shouldn't. You're teaching wrongly what the various representations of numbers mean. So, `0.5` equals `1/2` *only* if unlimited precision is allowed. And `0.3333` is not equal to `1/3`, of course.

Comment: @egreg I applaud the use of fractions :) but I was told that at a university lecture recently among 25 students asked what is 1/6+2/3 only one tried to get a fraction...and obtained 7/6! (all others thought it was a very tedious computation by hand, will all those digits after the decimal mark...)

Comment: @jfbu I know that the correct way is to learn them fractions, say you applaud. I would like the solution I'm asking for none the less. `:)` (The fact some people say it's too difficult to calculate, say, 1/6+2/3 by hand is a really bad excute for being lazy.)

Comment: @SvendTveskæg it was a bit with tongue in cheek as I have written thousands of lines of codes to be able to compute with fractions with `TeX`... `:-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [xintfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint). The package should have a native variant to its `\xintTrunc` or `\xintRound` routines which would strip trailing zeros, for lack of it I wrote a quick hack.

This initial hack was not completely satisfying (bad handling of integers). Here are two methods.

Update: the second method now allows **two** optional parameters, the first one is the number of digits after decimal mark (default `4`), the second one is the decimal mark (default `.`). And this is *expandable*.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\usepackage{multido}
% \usepackage[
%   round-mode = places,
%   round-precision = 4
% ]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\horse[1]{\calc{3.5*sin(pi/#1)}}
\newcommand*\horsenegative[1]{\calc{-3.5*sin(pi/#1)}}

\usepackage{xintfrac}

%///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
\makeatletter
% quickly written, there might be a simpler way
% you can modify \myNum@ to replace the dot by a comma if you prefer
% this method will work up to nine fixed point digits after decimal mark
% works also with negative numbers

% \def\myNum@ #1.{\the\numexpr #1.}% <- replace the last dot by the sep
%                                 % you need
% \newcommand*{\myNum}[1]{\xintRev{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
%                                  \myNum@\xintRev{\xintRound{4}{#1}}}}
% 
%\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

% but this had problems: would not handle well the case of integers, and even
% crash on zero, (\xintRound then does not print 0.0000 but just 0 without a
% dot). Here are now two general methods:

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% method allowing customizing on output of the decimal mark:
% (but needs some modifications to switch from 4 to another number of digits)
\newcommand*{\myNum}[1]{\expandafter\myNum@
                        \romannumeral0\xintround {4}{#1}0000\relax }
\def\myNum@ #1{\if#10\expandafter\myNum@zero\fi \myNum@@ #1}
\def\myNum@@ #1.#20000#3\relax{\ifx\relax#2\relax \expandafter\myNum@int\fi
                               #1,#2}% <- we use a comma as decimal mark
% as comma was used above, must also be used here:
\def\myNum@int #1,{#1}% <- case of an integral number (positive or negative)
\def\myNum@zero #1\relax{0}% <- case of zero                          

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% another way, easily generalized to any given number of digits,
%  (actually, generalization already done: nb of digits is optional arg)
% \newcommand*{\myNumVar}[2][4]{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
%                            \myNumVar@\xintREZ{\xintRound {#1}{#2}}}
% \def\myNumVar@ #1/1[#2]%
% {\xintifSgn {#2}{\xintTrunc {-#2}{#1[#2]}}{#1}{\xintNum{#1[#2]}}}

% now allows arbitrary separator as second optional argument:

% **** and is expandable! ****

\catcode`_ 11
\def\myNumVar #1{\myNumVar_chkopta #1\Z }
\def\myNumVar_chkopta #1{\ifx [#1\expandafter\myNumVar_opta
                             \else\expandafter\myNumVar_noopta
                         \fi #1}
\def\myNumVar_noopta #1\Z {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                           \myNumVar@\xintREZ{\xintRound {4}{#1}}.}
\def\myNumVar_opta [\Z #1]#2{\myNumVar_chkoptb #2\Z {#1}}
\def\myNumVar_chkoptb #1{\ifx [#1\expandafter\myNumVar_optb
                             \else\expandafter\myNumVar_nooptb
                         \fi #1}
\def\myNumVar_optb [\Z #1#2]#3{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                           \myNumVar@\xintREZ{\xintRound {#1}{#3}}{#2}}
\def\myNumVar_nooptb #1\Z #2{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                           \myNumVar@\xintREZ{\xintRound {#2}{#1}}.}
\catcode`_ 8

\def\myNumVar@ #1/1[#2]#3%
    {\xintifSgn {#2}{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                     \myNumVar@@ \xintTrunc {-#2}{#1[#2]}.{#3}}%
                    {#1}%
                    {\xintNum{#1[#2]}}}

\def\myNumVar@@ #1.#2.#3{#1#3#2}

\makeatother   

\begin{document}

\verb|\myNum| uses a comma on output:

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNum{\horse{\i}}\quad}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNum{\horsenegative{\i}}\quad}

\verb|\myNumVar| has an optional argument to specify the number of digits
(possibly zero) after the dot as decimal mark:

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [12]{\horse{\i}}\quad}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [12]{\horsenegative{\i}}\quad}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [0]{\horse{\i}}\quad}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [0]{\horsenegative{\i}}\quad}

\verb|\myNumVar| has a \textbf{second} optional argument to specify the
separator:

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [12][,]{\horse{\i}}\quad}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [12][,]{\horsenegative{\i}}\quad}

If you want to use crazy things like [ itself as separator you can do it:

\verb|\myNumVar [12][[]{stuff}|

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [12][[]{\horse{\i}}\quad}

But with ], use braces

\verb|\myNumVar [12][{]}]{stuff}|

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\myNumVar [12][{]}]{\horse{\i}}\quad}


Integral numbers do not have a decimal mark:

\myNum {-3.0000}=\myNumVar [5]{-3.0000}

\myNum {0.0000}=\myNumVar [13][!]{0.0000}

\myNum {-300.0000}=\myNumVar [7][;]{-300.0000}

\verb|\myNumVar| is expandable:\edef\test {\myNumVar [17][;]{1/1250}}

\verb|\edef\test {\myNumVar [17][;]{1/1250}}\meaning\test|
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\end{document}
```

[image: removal of zeroes]

Comment: I say this works with negative numbers, but there would be a problem with `-3.0000`, I don't have time to fix this now. Will provide complete solution later. (also I need to know if in case of `3.0000` the wanted thing is `3` or `3.`).

Comment: `3.0000` --> `3`. Thank you for the solution (and your upcomming improvement)!

Comment: @SvendTveskæg glad if it helps. I have replaced the initial slightly deficient hack by two methods. In the second method too, it would not be that hard now to add one extra layer to replace the dot by anything you want as decimal mark (on output).

Comment: Really nice. If you would generalize it to be abel to take both `.` and `,` as decimal separator, it would be really cool. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I have extended the second method to allow to specify the separator as a second optional argument. Notice that both the first and now the second method are completely expandable macros.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg ... I am aware I did not really answer your initial question, which was about using `siunitx` for that. Another thing worth mentioning is that once you switch the separator from `.` to something else, the `xint` macros will not be able to parse the result as input. If you want to do further computations with the data, this should be taken into account (naturally, there is no reason then to format prematurely, but you may wish to print intermediate results. A copy of the initial or rounded thing with `.` should then be kept handy).

Answer (score 4):

Since [v3.0](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/commit/4a7f71a5379a7cb3cf73b4f5197a1b0a23a38dc3) from 2021 there is a option `round-pad` which seems to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage[
  round-mode = places,
  round-precision = 4,
  round-pad = false %% true by default
]{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\horse[1]{\calc{3.5*sin(pi/#1)}}

\begin{document}

\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\num{\horse{\i}}\quad}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: v3 is not from 2018 but from May 2021 https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2843.1621343877.4615.ctan-ann@ctan.org ;)

Comment: Sorry, the patch was from 2018.

Answer (score 1):

A recommended solution with `fp` package.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{multido}
\newcommand*\horse[1]{\FPeval\calc{clip(trunc(3.5*sin(pi/#1):6))}\calc}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=2+1}{5}{\horse{\i}\quad}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I get a comma as decimal separator instead of a full stop?

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Yes, just pass it to `\num` with your `siunitx` settings. Expansion should be carefully considered, ask other people in the chat room to fix the expansion problem if you want to pass the value to `\num`.

Comment: *Recommended* by whom? If it's you that recommend it, just avoid saying it: presenting the solution is sufficient. Otherwise tell who's recommending the solution.

Comment: @egreg: By myself of course.

Answer (score 1):

You asked,

> Is it possible to remove the trailing zeros from the numbers?

Piece of cake with LuaLaTeX -- no need for the `siunitx` package and its `\num` macro. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luaexec' macro 
% Create 2 Lua functions, 'horse' and 'mynum':
\luaexec{
  function horse ( i )
    return ( 3.5 * math.sin ( math.pi / i ) )
  end
  function mynum ( j  )
    return ( string.format ( '\%.5g' , j ) )
  end
}
% Create a LaTeX wrapper macro for 'mynum' function:
\newcommand\mynum[1]{\directlua{tex.sprint(mynum(#1))}}

\begin{document}
\mynum{1.750000001}

\directlua { for i=2,6 do 
               tex.sprint ( mynum ( horse ( i ) ) .. '\\quad' )
             end
           }
\end{document}
```